# Trouble while adding south to existing app

Tags: python, django, migration, django-south

I am following the djano-rest-framework tutorial. I am trying to add south for db migration. This is what my `pip freeze` looks like:

```
Django==1.8.1
djangorestframework==3.1.2
MySQL-python==1.2.5
Pygments==2.0.2
South==1.0.2
```

My settings.py for the `tutorial` project looks like this:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'rest_framework',
    'snippets',
    'south'
)
...
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
        'NAME': 'snippets',
        'HOST': 'localhost',
        'PORT': 3306,
        'USER': 'abcd',
        'PASSWORD': ''
    }
 }

SOUTH_DATABASE_ADAPTERS = {
    'default': 'south.db.mysql'
}
```

I am getting the following error on running `./manage.py syncdb`:

```
/home/superq/learn-django/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/south/db/generic.py:9: RemovedInDjango19Warning: The django.db.backends.util module has been renamed. Use django.db.backends.utils instead.
  from django.db.backends.util import truncate_name

There is no South database module 'south.db.mysql' for your database. Please either choose a supported database, check for SOUTH_DATABASE_ADAPTER[S] settings, or remove South from INSTALLED_APPS.
```

I have already installed and uninstalled south multiple times. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using Django 1.8. There is no reason to add South: versions of Django since 1.7 have included built-in migrations. In fact, the South docs explicitly state that it is not compatible with 1.7+.

Comment: I opened the shell and tried to do 'import south'. It says no such module available.

Comment: Yes. Why would you do that? I just said, South is not necessary or compatible with 1.8.

Comment: I was trying because neither schemamigration or startmigration commands are available for manage.py

Comment: No, because Django 1.7/1.8 have their own migration commands, which are [fully explained in the documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/migrations/).

Comment: My bad. Will look at it thouroughly now. Any other example resources would also be appreciated. Thanks!